# Show that this construction preserves connectedness

Tags: graph-theory, problem-solving

Let $G_1$ and $G_2$ be $k$-connected graphs and let $v_1\in V(G_1)$ and $v_2\in V(G_2)$ be such that $\deg v_1=\deg v_2=k$. Form a new graph, $H$, by putting an $M$-matching of size $k$---conneect $N(v_1)$ with $N(v_2)$---between $G_1-v_1$ and $G_2-v_2$.

Show that $H$ is $k$-connected. I can easily show that $H$ is $(k-1)$-connected, but cannot show that it's $k$-connected. Any hints?

Answer (score 1):

Show that for every pair of vertices $x,y$ there are $k$ internally disjoint $x,y$-paths, then use Menger's theorem.

Distinguish two cases.

If $x$ and $y$ are in different graphs, say $x\in G_1-v_1$ and $y\in G_2-v_2$, use an $x,N(v_1)$-fan and an $y,N(v_2)$-fan and glue them together using the matching.

If $x$ and $y$ are in the same graph, say $G_1$, then you can find $k$ internally disjoint $x,y$-paths in $G_1$. At most one of these paths contains $v_1$ and then it contains two neighbours of $v_1$. Now redirect the part of the path between these neighbours via the other graph.

Comment: But when you delete vertices the graphs $G_1-v_1$ of $G_2-v_2$ might be $(k-1)$-connected and there need not be a $x,N(v_1)$ fan of size $k$. Or I am missing something?

Comment: You create the fan in $G_1$. $N(v_1)$ "protects" $v_1$ from being on any fan line, so it is still a fan in $G_1-v_1$.